# Gnome: Change title of current terminal from bash command line

Tags: bash, gnome, ubuntu-11.04, gnome-terminal

I know there are options to start a new terminal with a specified title, and that is is possible to change the title from a terminal using the menu: 'Terminal' -> Set Title.

However, I want to change it for a current terminal from command line. How can I change the title for an **existing** Gnome terminal from command line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Output a suitable xterm escape sequence.

```
echo -ne '\033]0;New title\007'
```

See also [How to change the title of an xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html).

Comment: Perfect, thats it! :D Also, thanks for the very interesting link.

Comment: Nice, but is it cross-platform compatible?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-448614.html - there is a discussion regarding other terminals. I don't have many measuring points, but the xterm variete at least works for me in rxvt-unicode as well.

Comment: @l0b0: Across which platforms? Many ssh clients on various platforms offer xterm compatibility, as do most xterm replacements.

Comment: @tripleee: Usually it's recommended to use `tput` commands to print such escape sequences, as mentioned in [this exact duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/23978/how-can-one-set-a-terminals-title-with-the-tput-command).

Comment: @l0b0: ack; you are right, of course.

Comment: @triplee Thanks for the input! However I don't consider this question as an exact duplicate of the one you mentioned. The context of the other question is very different.

Comment: This no longer seems to work

Comment: @kapad Where does this no longer work?  It works for me, still.

Comment: Warning, this will not work if PS1 and/or PROMT_COMMAND variables are set (in bashrc e.g. ) to set the title. In that case, after issuing this command, bash will first execute the contents of PROMT_COMMAND, then redraw the prompt ( = the text with the $-sign) by printing PS1. Both variables have the potential to reset the title. See the link in Zach Pfeffer's answer with more details (it's not only for Ubuntu).

Comment: That's `PROMPT_COMMAND` with a P. Your comment is a bit of a sweeping generalization; but certainly, if something else is rewriting the prompt (regularly or not), it will overwrite whatever you put there.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set it to the hostname where you are logged into you can use:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;${HOSTNAME}\007"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth your while to try KDE.  It has tabbed terminal windows, and each tab can be named just by right clicking on the tab.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, I'm still fond with Gnome :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04  you may need to clear the PS1 and PROMPT_COMMAND like:

```
PS1=$
PROMPT_COMMAND=
echo -en "\033]0;New title\a"
```

I put together a write up on it at [link](http://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/Change-the-title-of-a-terminal-on-Ubuntu-1604).