# How do you display hostname in tabs of console2?

Tags: bash, cygwin, console2

Is there a way to display the hostname as name of a tab in Console2?

If I use cygwin and ssh to a remote host, I would like the tab name to reflect
the remote hostname.

Comment: How do you start ssh? There is a question about [naming tabs in ConEmu](http://superuser.com/q/459154/139371). Take a look?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an X terminal emulator (such as Xterm) you can [use ANSI escape sequences to set the window title](https://superuser.com/questions/399812/gnome-change-title-of-current-terminal-from-bash-command-line). I don't know if Console2's ANSI support extends that far. Probably trying it is the easiest way to find out.

The Cygwin application [Mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/) *does* have the ANSI support you're looking for. Also, you can run an X terminal emulator (or any other X program) on your Windows desktop using X Server software such as [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) or [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/).